# How do I get the ip address of the remote endpoint of a socket of type boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>

Tags: ssl, boost, boost-asio

How do I get the ip address of the remote endpoint of a socket of type boost::asio::ssl::stream.  I want to print peer ip like this- but it doesnt work

```
std::cout << "Peer IP: " << socket_.remote_endpoint().address().to_string()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
It should be
            std::cout << "Peer IP: " << socket_.lowest_layer().remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;